# How do I parse a date string into a Joda DateTime object for java?

Tags: java, jodatime

The code below is the best I have come up with so far. The .setTime() methods are throwing a exception. Is there a better way to do this or correct this?

```
    String format = "MM/dd/yyyy";

    DateTime test = new DateTime();
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormat  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");

    SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat(format);

    String startDateString = "09/10/2015";
    String endDateString = "09/20/2015";
    Date startDate = null;
    Date endDate = null;
    Calendar sampleDateStart = null;
    Calendar sampleDateEnd = null;

    try{
        startDate = formater.parse(startDateString);
        endDate = formater.parse(endDateString);
        sampleDateStart.setTime(startDate);
        sampleDateEnd.setTime(endDate);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: NPE alert! :) Initialize your calendars with `Calendar.getInstance()`.

Comment: @rdm Glad to see you want participate in StackOverflow. Please search before posting. This site is meant to be a library of authoritative Questions and Answers, not an open-ended discussion group.

Comment: You say in title you need to "parse a date string into a Joda DateTime", but in comments to both answers you said you "need a calendar object". We can't help when *you* don't even know what you want.

Comment: @ Andreas You're right. Ill make that correction. Im a bit of a novice so a bit of a learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Seems fine if you fix the initialization of the `Calendar` variables:

```
Calendar sampleDateStart = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar sampleDateEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
```

The problem would have been more obvious if you had used the correct exception type as recommended,
instead of the generic `Exception`,
and printing the stack trace instead of `e.getMessage()`:

```
try {
    startDate = formater.parse(startDateString);
    endDate = formater.parse(endDateString);
    sampleDateStart.setTime(startDate);
    sampleDateEnd.setTime(endDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The stack trace would have told you the exact line where `NullPointerException` was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You already created the `DateTimeFormatter` that your need, so just use it:

```
DateTimeFormatter formater = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
DateTime startDateTime = formater.parseDateTime("09/10/2015");
DateTime endDateTime = formater.parseDateTime("09/20/2015");
```

No need for a `SimpleDateFormat` or a `Calendar`.

*Note:* I fixed the creation of the `DateTimeFormatter` to Joda, since you were doing it the Java 8 way.

Comment: The end result I need is a calendar object for another method

Comment: also your first line brings me errors suggesting DateTimeFormat be changed to DateTimeFormatter. Why is that?

Comment: Because you don't actually have Joda installed?